Android Settings panel not opening from my app
I'm trying to open the settings panel from my app but it is not doing anything, the device has Android 14 it's a Samsung A24.
I have another device which is the same model, where the code works. But I'm trying to understand why it doesn't work on the other device:
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        context.startActivity(Intent(Settings.Panel.ACTION_INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY))
 } else {
        val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS)
        context.startActivity(intent)
 }

I even tryed to validate if intent was not correct and open default settings app instead of the panel:
            Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked secondary button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                val intent = Intent(Settings.Panel.ACTION_INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY)
                if(intent.resolveActivity(context.packageManager) != null) {
                    context.startActivity(intent)
                    Log.d("No Internet view", "Opening wireless panel")
                } else {
                    context.startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS))
                    Log.d("No Internet view", "Opening wireless settings")
                }
            } else {
                val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS)
                context.startActivity(intent)
                Log.d("No Internet view", "Opening data roaming settings")
            }

However when run, i do receive the log "Opening wireless panel", but nothing is shown on screen.
Any hints on what can be different in a device that blocks this panel?
